# Different behavior of regexp() on linux and windows in matlab

Tags: regex, linux, windows, matlab

I am encountering a different behavior of [regexp()](https://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html#btn_p45_sep_shared-outkey) on linux and windows using MatLab.
I am trying to separate a string based on a separator. Here is a minimal example:

**Linux**

```
test_string = '<some_path>/tool/test/unit_test'
seperator = sprintf('%stest%s',filesep,filesep)
regexp(test_string, seperator,'split')
```

Output:

```
1×2 cell array
{'<some_path>/tool'}    {'unit_test'}
```

**Windows**

```
test_string = '<some_path>\tool\test\unit_test'
seperator = sprintf('%stest%s',filesep,filesep)
regexp(test_string, seperator,'split')
```

Output

```
1×1 cell array
{'<some_path>\src\tool\test\unit_test'}
```

The output of this code snippet on Linux represents the behavior I want. Could anyone explain or point towards resources to understand what is going on?

Comment: The path separators are different in Linux (`/`) and Windows (``\``). Use `[\\/]` to match both.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I'm using `filesep`, a matlab command to get the file seperator of the system. Also, `test_string` is composed using  `fullfile`.  So I do not expect this to be the issue

Comment: Ok, still the ``\`` is a problem since it is not doubled. A mere `filsep` will be ``\``, but you need two backslashes to match a literal backslash. So use `regexptranslate('escape',filesep)` instead of `filesep`.

Comment: If all you want to do is split a string, use `strsplit()`, which does exactly that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The path separators are different in Linux (`/`) and Windows (`\`).

The `\` character is a special regex metacharacter, it is used to form "regex escapes", like `\d` to match digits, etc. To match a literal backslash, it must be doubled, or *escaped*.

To escape any special regex metacharacters, you can use [`regexptranslate(op, str)`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexptranslate.html) with `op` set to `escape`:

```matlab
seperator = sprintf('%stest%s',regexptranslate('escape',filesep), regexptranslate('escape',filesep))
```

Other `op` possible values are:

| Type of Translation | Description |
| --- | --- |
| `'escape'` | Translate all special characters in str, such as `'$'`, `'.'`, `'?'`,`'['`, so that they are treated as literal characters when used in `regexp`, `regexpi`, and `regexprep`. The translation inserts a backslash, or escape, character, `'\'`, before each special character in `str`. |
| `'wildcard'` | Translate all wildcard and `'.'` characters in `str` so that they are treated as literal wildcard characters and periods when used in `regexp`, `regexpi`, and `regexprep`. The translation replaces all instances of `'*'` with `'.*'`, all instances of `'?'` with `'.'`, and all instances of `'.'` with `'\.'`. |
| `'flexible'` | Replace text in `str` with a regular expression that matches the text. If you specify `'flexible'`, then also specify a regular expression to use as a replacement: `newStr = regexptranslate('flexible',str,expression)`. The expression input can be a character vector or string scalar. This syntax is equivalent to `newStr = regexprep(str,expression,regexptranslate('escape',expression))`. |